# Chilufei Otiyot and the 22 Alef-Bets

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, aleph-bet-letters

In Sefer Yetzirah we are told of the 231 Gates, in various other sources we learn that there are many different Alef-Bets (Some saying as many as 231). Of these I know the standard, AtBash, AlBam, AchBi, Ayik Bekher, Achas Beta, and AtBach. What are the others? And can you please cite at least one source mentioning them directly. I also know the process of changing them is known as Chilufei Otiyot. I wish I could be more precise in citing works but I had most of my things stolen or destroyed a few years ago and I'm operating on memory and current attempts at finding the answer.

Comment: Hello Mikhael. Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: Where in Sefer Yetzirah does it say that? Just curious to look at the original wording.

Comment: In all honesty, this question has been on my mind for about 5 years and I don't remember precisely. I am going to look and then I'll edit this comment (Or post a new one) and let you know. I do know that Rabbi Yitzhak Ginsburg explained this at a lecture a number of years ago and that is much easier to reference (page 7 of this pdf http://www.inner.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/E66-0219-1.pdf )

The understanding comes from the 231 Shaarim of Sefer Yetzirah, I have tried to follow Rav Ginsburg's explanation but I would like independent sources to make sure that I understand him correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Moshe Cordovero lists the 22 alphabets in [Pardes Rimonim](http://www.hebrew.grimoar.cz/kordovero/pardes_rimonim.htm), Gate 30, Chapter 5:

> אלו הם כ"ב אלפ"א שבהם יתחלפו האותיות כאשר באו בספר יצירה וקראם רל"א
>   שערים מפני שהם רל"א זוגות
>
> אל בת גש דר הק וץ זף חע טס ין כמ
>
> אב גת דש הר וק זץ חף חע יס כן למ
>
> אג דת הש ור זק חץ טף יע כס לן במ
>
> אד בג הת וש זר חק טץ יף כע לס מן
>
> אה בר ות זש חר טק ין כף לע מס גן
>
> או בה גד זת חש טג יק כץ לף מע נס
>
> אז בו גה חת טש יד כק לץ חף נע דס
>
> אח בז גו דה טת יש כר לק מץ נף סע
>
> אט בח גז דו ית כש לר מק נץ סף הע
>
> אי בט גח דז הו כת לש מר נק סץ עף
>
> אב בי גט דח הז לת מש נר סק עץ יף
>
> אל בך גי דט הח וז מת נש סר עק פץ
>
> אמ בל גס די הט זה צת סש ער פק זן
>
> אג בם גך דק הי וט זח סת עש פר צק
>
> אס בג גמ דל הס וי זט עת פש צר חק
>
> אע בס גנ דמ הל וכ זי חט פת צש קר
>
> אף בע גס דנ המ ול זכ חי צת קש טר
>
> אץ בף גע דס הג ומ זל חס טי קת רש
>
> אק בץ גף דע הס וג זם חל טב רת יש
>
> אר בק גץ דף הע וס זג חמ טל יב שת
>
> אש בר גק דן הף וע זס חג טמ יל כת
>
> את בש גר דק הץ וף זע חס טן ימ כל
>
> ע"כ נשלמו רל"א שערים שבספר יצירה ובהם מתחלפות האותיות כל אשר יצטרף אל
>   החילוף השמות והכחות